# Is it possible to use a custom Lottie animation as a map marker with the Google Maps api?

Tags: android, google-maps, lottie

I'm creating a custom map screen using the GoogleMaps api, and want to create map markers using a custom Lottie animation, rather than a static bitmap. Is this possible?

Comment: Did you get the answer?

Answer (score 0):

No, there is no any native api which provide `Lottie` animation to set inside Map Marker. Though you can use your custom animation eg, using native animation api to update position, alpha or icons with some delay.